# Getting an error while creating custom index in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my firestore query similar to this code:

```
events.where("placeName", "==", place.name)
      .where("date", ">=", date1)
      .where("date", "<=", date2)
      .get()
      .then(eventSnapshot => {
          eventSnapshot.forEach(eDoc => {
                //DOING SOMETHING WITH DATA
          });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log("ERROR__:    " + error))
```

I'm getting this error.

`FirebaseError: [code=failed-precondition]: The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/etkinlik-yogunluk-haritasi/database/firestore/indexes?create_index=EgZldmVudHMaDQoJcGxhY2VOYW2lEAIaCAoEZGF0ZRACGgwKCF9fbmFtZV9fEAI`

But when I click the link I'm getting this 
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJeMx.png). Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you try to create the index manually and not by the proposed link?

Comment: It still gives me the same error

Comment: Can you try to leave the account, reconnect to the Internet and login again?

Comment: I tried everything and did the same in different browser but nothing changed.